# Google maps V3 API key usage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key

Sounds stupid, but since there is no specific example in documentation, its not clear how to use the api key. 
**This part of code from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=cs) is not clear:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
```

Well I will find my apikey, let's say that the value of my api key will be for example: 123456ABCDEFG

So how should I used it?

1)`src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={123456ABCDEFG}&sensor=false"`
**or** 
2)`src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=123456ABCDEFG&sensor=false"`

or else?

Comment: Google's documentation is terrible, as well as their developer console navigation.  I had the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget the `equals`.

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=123456ABCDEFG&sensor=false"
```